# How can I monitor server varialbes with Microsoft Network Monitor?

Tags: iis, network-monitoring

I'd like to understand how IIS server populates the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and the REMOTE_ADDR server variables, how can I "parse" manually the values that IIS is using to determine these variables by inspecting the frame summary in Microsoft Network Monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [this aricle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx) (although old), I would assume the REMOTE_ADDR server variable is populated based on the source address of the IP header field from the initiating connection. Any server variable preceded by HTTP_ are populated by the HTTP headers sent in the request. Hence, the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR server variable is populated if the HTTP request is populated with an X-Forwarded-For header, with the dash (-) interpreted as an underscore (_).

Unless an HTTP module interferes with the data structure, the values, when read from a network monitor recorded on the server would be:

- **REMOTE_ADDR**: Source IP from incoming packets, Destination IP from outgoing packets. If the network trace is captured from the client it *may* be vice versa, unless there are other devices between the browser and web server.
- **HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR**: If sent, the X-Forwarded-For header of an HTTP request. For SSL traffic, the server certificate's private key may be required to decrypt the traffic.